# My Robot is Having Trouble Sharp Turn and Narrow Corridor

Tags: navigation, differential-drive, rplidar, diff-drive-controller

[image]

https://youtu.be/-bgO7hgdRD4

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hppDQvYpovI

Hi everyone, ı build a robot which is rectangular shape 42cmx23cm, ı get into the 40cm narrow corridors and robots can get into the all corridor with circularly, my problem is my robot cant turn sharp, robots need turn 90 degree for get into and get out the corridor, but while do that my robot is rubbing in corners, what I tried before for improve this problem

- I use diff-drive-controller from ros2 and I feed with wheel encoder
- Check Lidar Position
- Try ekf (wheel odom & imu)
- Set Robot_footprint tightly
- Create map with slam_toolbox
- I try different planners (NAVFN, DWB, **SMAC2D**)
- I try different controllers (RPP and **DWB**)
- Change parameters for local costmap

  ```
   cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
   inflation_radius: 0.19
   resolution: 0.01
   width:1
   height:1
  ```
- Change parameters for global costmap

  ```
  cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
  inflation_radius: 0.40
  resolution: 0.01 ()
  ```
- Nav2 params yaml file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f962CICoAGLT75KYO0rs9HUC23zFHPi1/view?usp=drive_link

My real question is, what other settings can I change? Can you recommend me a different controller or planner? Should I add new sensors?